# I put ref to my input.But i can't focus with it,why?

Tags: vue.js

I wanted to make a basic todo app. There are input and label on top of each other. There is a variable "editMode" in my state and it is false by default.
if "editMode" is true, my label will disappear and input will appear. I placed
@dblclick to my label. When this invoked "editMode" will become true and I want to focus my input field.

I put ref on the input element. So user double click the label, I wanted to focus my input with "this.$refs.input.focus()".I also tried  this.$nextTick

this is my template

```
  <div class="todo">
    <div class="todo-left">
      <input type="checkbox" class="completed"/>
    </div>
    <div class="todo-middle">
      <label v-if="!editMode" @dblclick="activateEditMode">{{text}}</label>
      <input type="text" v-model="text" v-show="editMode" ref="input">
    </div>
    <div class="todo-right" v-if="!editMode">
      <span>❌</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and  this is script

```
<script>
export default {
    name:'TodoItem',
    data:function(){
      return {
        editMode:false,
        text:'Go to shopping'
      }
    },
    methods:{
      activateEditMode:function(){
        this.editMode=true;
        this.$nextTick(()=>{
          this.$refs.input.focus()
        })

      },
      onClickOutside:function(e){
        const { input} =this.$refs
        if(input && !input.contains(e.target)){
          this.editMode=false
        }

      }
    },
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener("click", this.onClickOutside);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.onClickOutside);
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talkhabi/3ksvo860/)

Comment: Yeah, it works. I've been looking for a solution for three hours. The only thing I haven't tried is to restart the application.